# Does Science contradict Hinduism? How to deal with scientific discoveries that don't line up with Vedas?

Tags: vedas, philosophy, science, pramana

I would like to know if Hinduism and science contradict each other. This is an issue that arises in many religions, the most prominent example being Christianity and its [disagreement with evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Earth_creationism). So how does Hinduism deal with this?

If I am a Hindu, does that mean that I cannot accept what science has discovered?

Do Hindu scriptures mention how to deal with scientific findings that may not line up with the Vedas?

Comment: Never. Science and Spirituality go hand in hand. And spirituality is the base if Hinduism.

Comment: The question is more like does science contradict science?

Comment: They do not. Hinduism is the most scientific religion. As for science itself, you must not forget that it is still evolving and up for re-interpretation. Science is yet to find the ultimate truth. In its path to do so, it has only corroborated what the vEdAs have stated. for e.g., Atomic theory exists in the shastras, the scientific approach itself is a darsana, and so on.

Comment: @moonstar2001 What do you mean?

Comment: @Ajay OK. Perhaps re-reading  my comment a couple of times will help you understand?

Comment: Vedas cover both material and spiritual science keeping well being of life at its core. Science only covers material aspect and may or may not be for the well being of life. It will take atleast 400 years to master all the Vedangas. Science is just at the baby stage compared to the age of the Vedas. Just quoting scriptures to prove a point of view has no material or spiritual value. Actual practice and self realization will lead to a better understanding of life. All the best!

Comment: Sanaatana Dharma aka Hinduism is basically oriented towards sprituality.  Vedas lay emphasis on Self-enquiry only.  Ritualistic Religions like  Vaishnavism, Shaivism, etc, is a later date development.  Self enquiry itself indicates scientific temperament. So there is no contradiction between Scientific temperament and Sanaatana Dharma.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indus_Valley_Civilisation#Technology)  @Akshay

Comment: No, they do not contradict. The entire notion of science is hinged upon the concept of 'falsifiability', and being able to prove hypotheses. unfortunately, today's half-baked pseudo-scientists are unwilling to extend that concept to claims found in religious texts. As discussed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34352/is-religion-different-from-science-especially-when-it-comes-to-falsifiability) .. @sv

Comment: Yes Hinduism and science contradict a lot. About he age of the earth, the size of the universe, the age limit of people etc.

Comment: It would have helped immensely if you would have given some examples of contradiciton. Evolution is a theory there is no scientific finding to corroborate.

Comment: it should followed by why science contradicts itself..like light is wave or matter how the cosomos be defiened with single unified theory why laws of physical physics fail in quatam, why quatam is not able applicable to macro particle..

Comment: Science tried to develop theory for everything but unfortunately it failed badly.. it tried to explain only material particle it doenst speak about soul atman. supreme soul.. sprituality starts where science ends.

Comment: @sv. Can we send award bounty as many times as we want?

Comment: @sv. Are new answers qualified to receive the bounty or have you already decided to award the bounty to the answer that you refer to?

Comment: Yes, in increasing amounts until you hit the max bounty of 500. If I think a particular answer is worth 5000 points, I have to award the bounty at least 10 times. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: More or less decided to award the bounty to the top-voted answer here, BUT, if you write something unique (i.e., not already covered in one of the answers here) and with lots of [references](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126), then I may award the bounty to you.

Comment: @PrakashK "Evolution is a theory there is no scientific finding to corroborate." Wrong. Evolution is a die hard fact which has a lot of scientific evidence.

Comment: @Wikash_ Thank you for pointing out my ignorance. Can you please provide one or two links which give it as a "die-hard fact"? Better still why not edit the question and provide examples of scientific discoveries which are factual with references and which  you think contradict. This would be of great service. Thank you.

Comment: @prakashK "provide examples of scientific discoveries which are factual with references and which you think contradict". What do you mean? Contradict what? Hinduism?

Comment: My answer will be that if anything which contradict Science then consider it as *Superstition* but I am sure that there is always a hidden meaning of Paragraph which you when decode then you will find that things written in Bhagvad Gita, UPNISHAD have said things in a very logical sence !!

Comment: Depends many scientific claims are fact ie the Earth is round. However, the theory of evolution while the most likely and plausible claim with evidence isn't necessarily a fact creationism and evolution could still occur. In my opinion, Hindu texts could likely contradict science and I am willing to stop believing not abandoning, but believing in my religion if such is the case for major texts. But, before this one should read text using Sanskrit many English translations are horrible connections with Sanskrit words. Like Nakshatra meaning star meaning when--

Comment: in actuality, it translated more accurately to the lunar mansion and celestials associated with the moon. An similar can be said for words like Loka and Graha.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hinduism is an **intrinsically scientific** religion.

The Vedas themselves accurately describe very complicated geometric concepts including six-dimensional spaces, distances between celestial bodies, and using changing skylines to measure time, just to name a few examples ("Vedic Geometry Course" Dr. S. K. Kapoor). If you follow the Dhashavataram carefully, you will see that it perfectly mirrors the evolution of life on Earth as well as the emergence of increased social structure (and eventual decline) among humans.

Furthermore, it has been written that the Vedas themselves are to be consulted only in matters which **cannot** be resolved by either *Pratyaksha* (direct observation) or *Anumana* (inferences and inductions based on said observations, or in other words **science**).

The third category of knowledge, *Sabda*, refers to the Vedas themselves. Smritis, Itihasas, and Puranas are also included here where they "do not contradict the Vedas". *Sabda* is to be relied on to resolve questions which either have not yet been answered by *Pratyaksha* and *Anumana* (e.g. how does physics behave in a six-dimensional space?) or cannot be answered (e.g. what happens to the *Atma* after death?).

Info above paraphrased from: "A Dialogue on Hinduism", Sri V. N. Gopala Desikan, pg. 24-25

In other words, Vedas and science do not contradict each other. They lie **orthogonal** to each other. Our gurus want us to use science to answer any worldly questions, and seek the Vedas for matters that science does not or cannot answer.

Ultimately, Hinduism is a very scientific religion. Many of our beliefs stem directly from scientific facts (ritual purity and not shaving during certain months just to name a few). The idea that one can either be a scientist or a Hindu but not both is simply untrue.

In summary, I'll leave you with this quote from "A Dialogue on Hinduism":

> Student: I do not understand why logic should not be used to discuss Brahman.
>
> Guru: Logic will be useful, when we discuss about known things, so that, with authority, we can make use of our logic and argument. But logic **cannot** be of use, in discussing about unknown things, unseen things like Brahman.
>
> Student: Does this mean that logic cannot be used at all for studying or understanding Brahman?
>
> Guru: No, it is not that. The primary authority is the Vedas and these can be **supplemented** by logic, **without deviating** from the authority of the Vedas.

Comment: "Hinduism is an intrinsically scientific religion" - please tell me what is "scientific" about Indra cursing (or "distributing sin") among all women with menstruation? See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17618/2995) answer. "without deviating from the authority of the Vedas" - I tend to think the moment you accept the authority of any book, scripture, guru or even a scientist, without debate and dialogue, all common sense is lost.

Comment: @sv nice you wrote "i tend to think". Even if vedas try to explain you spiritual concept its difficult for the conditioned mind to grasp the full import just like a kindergarten does not understand where baby's come from and you can't even explain to them. So i tend to think, we need authority to tell us till the time we become spiritual adults and somethings no matter how much you wrack your brain you might not be able to get. And material science is limited by our tiny brain. And discussion and questions are there in the scriptures, is it not :)

Comment: @PrakashK The question ("Do Hindu scriptures mention how to deal with scientific findings that may not line up with the Vedas?") is about science, not spirituality. If I point out any error in an article published in a scientific journal, that article (part of the journal) is rejected by the community. Can we do the same with Vedas or any Hindu scriptures whenever a claim is found be wrong upon verification? If not, does it mean our brains are hardwired to blindly accept the authority of the Vedas or a guru? BTW, Muslims think Quran is flawless and Christians think the same of Bible.

Comment: @PrakashK Read the final line in this answer: "Guru: No, it is not that. The primary authority is the Vedas and these can be supplemented by logic, without deviating from the authority of the Vedas." -- what this means is, science is acceptable to the extent it doesn't deviate from the Vedas.

Comment: "*including six-dimensional spaces*" i would really love to see that being presented here than said. Atleast provide a link ? Further , measuring time using changing skylines, distance between some celestial objects is not very "modernly" scientific but are done from thousands of years ago.

Answer (score 47):

Science must be accepted even when science contradicts the Vedas. Vedas should be used only in matters which can not be probed by any scientific method. Vedic authority does not extend to matters which can be studied using scientific methods. I am posting some quotes that will hopefully make things clear.

Bhishma [said](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a141.htm) in Mahabharata Shanti Parva Section CXLII:

> Even the words heard from an ignorant person, if in themselves they be
>   fraught with sense, come to be regarded as pious and wise. In days of
>   old, Usanas said unto the Daityas this truth, which should remove all
>   doubts, **that scriptures are no scriptures if they cannot stand the
>   test of reason.**

Acharya Shankara, for example, in his [Gita Bhasya 18.66](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=ro&field_chapter_value=18&field_nsutra_value=66&etgb=1&setgb=1&choose=1) says:

> The appeal to the infallibility of the Vedic injunction is
>   misconceived. The infallibility in question refers only to the unseen
>   forces or apurva, and is admissible only in regards to matters not
>   confined to the sphere of direct perceptions, etc ... **Even a
>   hundred statements of sruti to the effect that fire is cold and
>   non-luminous won't prove valid.** If it does make such a statement, its
>   import will have to be interpreted differently. Otherwise, validity
>   won't attach to it. Nothing in conflict with the means of valid
>   cognition or with its own statements may be imputed to sruti.

REF: Srimad Bhagavad Gita Bhasya of Sri Sankaracarya translation by Dr. A. G. Krishna Warrier, p. 629.

[Yoga Vasistha II.18](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-sanskrit/d/doc249996.html) says:

> *yuktiyuktamupādeyaṃ vacanaṃ bālakādapi* | 
>   *anyattṛṇamiva tyājyamapyuktaṃ padmajanmanā* || 3 ||
>
> ---
>
> The remark of a child is to be accepted, if it is in accordance with
>   reason; but the remark of even Brahma Himself, the creator of the
>   world is to be rejected like a piece of straw if it does not accord
>   with reason.

REF: Vasistha's Yoga translated by Swami Venkatesananda, p 35.

Sri [Vachaspati Mishra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C4%81caspati_Mi%C5%9Bra), another Advaita Vedanta philosopher, [says](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.105465#page/n526/mode/1up/search/vacaspati+says),

> *Na hy āgamāḥ sahasram api ghaṭam paṭayitum īṣate* (Bhāmatī, Introduction)
>
> A thousand scriptures cannot make a jar into a cloth.

REF: Quoted by S. Radhakrishnan in his book, [Indian Philosophy, Volume 2](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.105465/page/n11).

Comment: Advatins may believe that sensory evidence ought to hold higher authority compared to Shruti, but that's hardly a universally held view in Hinduism.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Do you seriously believe the genesis myths in Hinduism? You may find layers and layers of allegories but it's really disappointing in literal sense.

Comment: @VineetMenon Yes, I really do believe that our creation stories literally took place as described in, say, the Srimad Bhagavatam.

Comment: I was trying to check for sources to support your answer and I found many sources but the author is you only. nice :D

Comment: I have given more details about the sources of my references.

Comment: The quote from the Mahabharata isn't saying that we shouldn't listen to scriptures if it contradicts reason.  It's saying the opposite: real scriptures constitute the truth, so no proper application of reason can possibly contradict scripture.  That's why the passage also says "They that are really breakers of morality find fault with the scriptures", and that those who "decry scriptures" and those that proclaim that "scriptural injunctions are unsound" are "Rakshasas among men."

Comment: The passage is saying that if an attempted application of reason is contradiction with scripture, then either reason hasn't been properly applied (the sensory evidence may be faulty or the scientific theory may be incorrect) or the scripture is being misunderstood.

Comment: The plain meaning of the passage clearly says that a scripture is no scripture if it can not stand the test of reason.

Comment: This answer is quite misleading. Please post the reference to Sanskrit and translation before using Bhisma and Sankara in support of your answer.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, I like your bold comments based on the scriptural truth rather than speculative ideas

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan How does this answer the question at all and why was it not downvoted/flagged as irrelevant?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Advaitins hold sensory experience superior to sruti? No sir. Thats charavakas. Advaitins believe in sastra (veda/sruti).

Comment: @moonstar2001 It does answer the question.  (Whether the answer is right or wrong is another matter.). Pradip's answer is that we should accept science over Hindu scripture if a conflict between the two ever arises.

Comment: @moonstar2001 " "Advaitins hold sensory experience superior to sruti? No sir. Thats charavakas. Advaitins believe in sastra (veda/sruti)." Yes, Advaitins believe in Hindu scripture, but that's not the issue.  The issue is whether they believe that sensory evidence should be accepted over scripture if and when the two conflict.  And Adi Shankaracharya's quote arguably shows that they do: "Even a hundred statements of sruti to the effect that fire is cold and non-luminous won't prove valid."

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan They do not. First, that quote needs to be verified. Second, even if it were true, that statement does not hold sensory perception superior to sruti but rather truth. For fire is hot and if it is stated that is it cold, then the statement is to be discounted. Truth is superior. Thats what it means. Light years of difference between truth and indriyanubhavam. Truth (aka Sat) - everlasting and unchanging is superior to all. For us advaitins, "tasmachastram pramanam".

Comment: @moonstar2001 Well, what about the quote "The infallibility in question refers only to the unseen forces or apurva, and is admissible only in regards to matters not confined to the sphere of direct perceptions"?   In any case you can read Adi Shankaracharya's commentary on the verse here: http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-18-66/

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan  Adi Sankaracharya does not put  sensory perception above sastra! No sane guru does! In fact, all advaita practices insist on conquering the senses in the pursuit of the ultimate truth. I guess you have to be born an advaitin to not dilute or misinterpret Sankaracharya's teachings.

Comment: @moonstar2001 "Adi Sankaracharya does not put sensory perception above sastra! No sane guru does! In fact, all advaita practices insist on conquering the senses in the pursuit of the ultimate truth." Well, those things aren't necessarily contradictory. You could believe that sensory evidence is the most reliable means of acquiring truth concerning the (illusory) material world, and yet believe that scripture is the most reliable means of acquiring truth about the spiritual world. In any case, if you think Pradip's answer is mischaracterizing Shankaracharya's views, you can take it up with him.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan One can believe that sensory evidence is supreme  but that theory has been well defeated by Sankaracharya with simple logic.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Did Adi Shankaracharya specifically refute the claim that sensory evidence has supremacy *in the sensory realm*, even if it doesn't have supremacy in all domains?  Do you have quotes to that effect?  In any case, maybe you should write an answer of your own, to provide an alternative view on the Advaitin conception of the role of sensory evidence and science.

Comment: Thank you @sv for these points.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan do you also believe that Moon is further than Sun as stated in Shirmad Bhagavatam??

Answer (score 8):

I believe that science and hinduism are not that different and not at all contradictory.

But it must be said that in order to see the similarities, it is needed to dive deep into Hinduism and Hindu beliefs. Some of the Hinduism philosophies here has been following the Advaita Vedanta stance and some others the Achithyabedhabheda stance, some the Dvaita stance. It is mainly to highlight the similarities in observations, although conclusions vary.

Here are some examples in plain English to support my point:

[Science: Energy can neither be created nor destroyed. Matter can be decomposed into energy as per E=mc2 which means energy is present in matter as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy)

Hinduism: God is without beginning nor end (i.e) He was neither created nor destroyed, He takes various forms and is present in everything, including his creation (matter)?

[Science: Every matter exhibits properties as a particle and as a wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality). In fact it simultaneously exhibits properties of both particle (something that can be seen/touched/heard/felt or smelt) and wave-nature (something which cannot be directly seen/touched/heard/felt or smelt but which can be perceived through existence of a 'medium' (in case of mechanical waves) or a 'field' (in case of electromagnetic waves).

Hinduism: [There is both a form nature and a formless nature](http://www.enlightened-spirituality.org/Our_Real_Nature.html) to every being, the form nature refers to the physical body, which can be perceived by the senses and the formless nature refers to the mind, which can be perceived through the body.

Science: Vacuum is not empty, but is filled with some kind of radition (cosmic microwave background, which is believed to be present since the Big Bang), energy (dark energy) or some kind of particles (vacuum state, a set of particles coming in and out of existence) [Wiki1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_state),[Wiki2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background),[Wiki3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy). Hinduism: The cosmic sound (or vibration) Om fills all of existence and it is the back-bone of all creation.

[Science: All of the objects in the observable universe are controlled by the three laws of motion.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion) The first law is that of inertia (or inability to change its own state of rest or motion), the second law deals with acceleration under influence of force and the third law deals with action-reaction balance.

Hinduism: All of [existence is under control of the three gunas (or tendencies)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CE4QFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hinduwebsite.com%2Fgunas.asp&ei=5CgkVLOzK4G2yAS_14KQDQ&usg=AFQjCNFsBMcO70sAtVo13AgKrp3XoKWTbw&sig2=0BdMEu83ld_nDrcNIgK4rw)? The first is that of Tamas (kind of laziness or lethargy, unwillingness to change one's present state), the second is that of Rajas (kind of excitation or passionate activity under influence of tendencies and desires, equivalent to acceleration under force), the third is that of Sattva (the state of non-judgement, purity, or balanced state of mind)?

Science: All matter in the universe was formed from a [single point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang), which expanded into the various masses and energies that are present today. This is the most accepted view of creation called the Big Bang. Without this assumption several scientific postulates made are simply invalid.

Hinduism: Initially there was only One. [The One became two and the two became many](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/hinduism/concepts/advaita.asp). This One is God (called Vishnu by Vaishnavas, Shiva by Shaivas and Brahman by Vedantis). All of creation was formed from Him and are thus pervaded by Him. This point of origin is God.

BUT What about evolution?

According to Hinduism, the avatars of Lord Vishnu beliefs:

1. Matsya (Fish)   AQUATIC
2. Kurma (Tortoise)  AMPHIBIOUS
3. Varaha (Boar)  LAND ANIMAL
4. Narahari (Half-man half-lion) PRE-EVOLVED HUMAN BEINGS ([missing link to evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitional_fossil#Missing_links)??)
5. Vamana (Dwarf human)    EARLY HUMANs
6. Parasurama (Axe weilder, Kshatriya slayer, super powered)  NOMADIC HUMANS
7. Rama (Ideal man)     HUMANs
8. Krishna (super-powered and all-knowing, embodiment of love and beauty)    (FUTURE/GOAL of Human life?)

NOTE: In no way am I trying to compare Lord Rama to our current Humans or Lord Parashurama to Nomadic humans. But I am merely trying to point toward the similarity between beliefs and the possible inner meanings behind our beliefs, that there is more to Hinduism than what people observe normally.

There are many more examples in which Science and Hinduism cross-over and speak of same things. However it is necessary to dive deep into both religion and science in order to understand their relationship. My own personal opinion is that religion is the fullness of science. Where science uses techniques of observation and experimentation to understand the unapparent from the apparent (kind of a top down approach, which does give rise to lot of [unsolved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_physics) problems), religion uses techniques of inquiry and practice to understand the apparent from usage of unapparent (kind of a bottom-up approach).

Therefore if I am a scientist, should I accept what Hinduism says? If I am a Hindu should I accept what Science says? There is no need to accept without understanding, the only answer to this question is to first understand Hinduism and then decide to accept it or not, similar with science.

Comment: Interesting interpretation of the *avatars*. I've always thought that *Narasimha* represents the emergence of carnivorous animals (following to *Varaha* who is herbivorous).

Comment: "God takes various forms" doesn't in any way state wave and matter. It was most likely a reference to rebirth, avatars and manifestation in various forms.

Comment: @Wally I dont understand sir. What do you mean. Where is it written in this answer that God taking various forms has a relationship with wave and matter duality? In this answer, it is written that the wave particle duality indicates the formless Vs form-ful nature of Man. Wave is analogous to the formless nature of Man, whereas a particle is analogous to the form-ful nature of Man. Am I missing something in your comment?

Comment: @Wally I see the source of your confusion. You have to read in this order, first the scientific principle is stated and then its analogous Hinduism concept is stated. i.e. God taking various forms, refers to the scientific belief that Energy can only be tranformed from one form to another, but can neither be created nor destroyed. The second example of waves and matter are analogous to formless and formful nature of creation as explained above. All the best!

Comment: "science and hinduism are not that different and not at all contradictory" - How do you explain Indra cursing (or "distributing sin") among all women as menstruation? See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17618/2995) answer. What is 'scientific' about this? How do you tell a Hindu woman the SB story is not to be taken seriously? Maybe it's written for the illiterate who don't know science well?

Comment: @sv. good question! the account of Indra cursing all women as menstruation is part of puranic tradition. For me Hinduism is very vast, just like science. It starts with the stories of Puranas, continues into the philosophy of Upanishads, practice of yoga and ends in self realization and explanations of Saints, One who stops with the story of Purana is similar to concluding that the rudimentary science we learn in elementary school is all there is to science. In this answer we are mainly comparing the yogic and upanishad teachings of hinduism to science, except the analogy of dashavatar.

Comment: You forget Buddha en kalki. Your post makes no sense at all. You are comparing apples with oranges. Comparing god with energy is wrong: energy can be converted god cannot be converted. Energy can be harnessed and used god cannot be used. Energy can be assigned a quantity god can not be assigned a number.

Comment: @Wikash_ Good points, I would like to propose that we both start a chat since I can see that between your point of view and mine there is a large gap and we cannot resolve within 35 character comments. In short here are my replies to your statements: 'Energy can be converted from one form to another', same way the One formless God assumes various forms for the sake of His devotees. 'Energy can be harnessed.' Similarly the God within you can be harnessed (that's what Yoga is all about!). 'Energy can be assigned a quantity'. The 'amount of energy' can be assigned a quantity, but energy cannot.

Comment: @Wikash_ Also another source of confusion maybe your understanding of 'God' versus mine. If you are coming from a Christian or dualistic school of thought, God is typically described as a Person with personality, similar to us human beings. However in Hinduism, there are several viewpoints on what God is. My answer here is more from a advaita and yoga perspective that God is formless, attributeless Consciousness. In that sense, there are several analogies between God and the concept of Energy mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

So before answering your question i would like start with quotes

> "'Astonishing fact! The Hindu Revelation (Veda) is all relavations the only one whose ideas are in perfect harmony with Modern Science, as it proclaims the slow and gradual formation of the world.'" (The Bible in India by Jacolliot, Vol II, Chapter 1)
>
> 'It (Vedic Religion) recognizes but One God. It is a thoroughly scientific religion where religion and science meet hand in hand. Here theology is based upon science and philosophy.' (The Superiority of the Vedic Religion by W.D. Brown)

Now coming to the answers I have certain excerpts from books written by western authors.

To the philosophers of India, however, Relativity is no new discovery, just as the concept of light years is no matter for astonishment to people used to thinking of time in millions of kalpas, (A kalpa is about 4,320,000 years). The fact that the wise men of India have not been concerned with technological applications of this knowledge arises from the circumstance that technology is but one of innumerable ways of applying it.

- Sir John Woodroffe, A Tribute to Hinduism, page 246

> The Indians came closest to modern ideas of atomism, quantum physics, and other current theories.
>
> The Rig-Veda, is the first Indian literature to set down ideas resembling universal natural laws. Cosmic law is connected with cosmic light, with gods, and, later, specifically with Brahman. It was the Vedic Aryans... who gave the world some of the earliest philosophical texts on the makeup of matter and the theoretical underpinnings for the chemical makeup of minerals. Sanskrit Vedas from thousands of years before Christ implied that matter could not be created, and that the universe had created itself.
> Two thousand years before Pythagoras, philosophers in northern India had understood that gravitation held the solar system together, and that therefore the sun, the most massive object, had to be at its center." "Twenty-four centuries before Isaac Newton, the Hindu Rig-Veda asserted that gravitation held the universe together. The Sanskrit speaking Aryans subscribed to the idea of a spherical earth in an era when the Greeks believed in a flat one. The Indians of the fifth century A.D. calculated the age of the earth as 4.3 billion years; scientists in 19th century England were convinced it was 100 million years.

- Dick Teresi, Lost Discoveries: The Ancient Roots of Modern Science

> Hindu are more exact in astronomy and astrology than any other people.

- Tarikh al-Yaqubi, The Foundations of the Composite Culture in India, page 59

> Long before it became a scientific aspiration to estimate the age of the earth, many elaborate systems of the world chronology had been devised by the sages of antiquity. The most remarkable of these occult time-scales is that of the ancient Hindus, whose astonishing concept of the Earth's duration has been traced back to Manusmriti, a sacred book.

- Professor Arthur Holmes, Hinduism And Scientific Quest, page 20

> So, these are few that perfectly say how Hinduism (Sanatan Dharma) is and has always been sync with Science.

Comment: Let me point out that a light year is not a unit of time but a unit of distance: One light year is the distance light travels in one year. The star nearest to us is at a distance of about 4 light years. Secondly: Concerning relativity I assume you allude to Einsteins Special theory of relativity or his General theory of relativity. Could you please name a location from Indian philosophy which anticipates these 20-th century's theories?

Comment: @jowehler from what I understand time dilation is a process or theory using Einstein's theories of relativity. According to this time is a dimension and different observers on different gravitational bodies observe time differently (or something like that, you can refer wikipedia) the consequence is that time here is different than time in space or time in Mars, or time in another planet. In most Hindu scriptures, the concept of time as a dimension is clearly seen. For example, it is said that one year of Brahma (on Brahma loka or Brahma's 'world') is equivalent to X years on Earth.

Comment: @Sai I doubt that any time difference between earth and mars can be measured, because both planets do not differ enough with respect to the gravitation on their surface. Furthermore: To check the statement referring to Brahma loka, could you please supply the value of the gravitation in Brahma loka as well as the value of the conversion factor 'X'.

Comment: @jowehler I see you are looking to satisfy some kind of equation to 'check' whether it equates and holds true. I doubt such values will be found in scripture. But rather my point is about the similarity between the findings of both science and scripture. While science has recently 'found' that due to time dilation, time on various celestial bodies will differ from each other and only last couple of centuries has theorized that time is a dimension subject to modification, this information was already present and being used in Hindu scriptures :). is this not the info u were seeking sir?

Comment: @Sai Due to the theory of general relativity a clock at the surface of the sun runs slower than a clock at the surface of the earth by a factor of about 1/1.000.000. That's a precise numerical prediction. On the other hand, general claims that gods have a different time scale than humans can be found in different religions, e.g. in the Christian religion, too. In my opinion, such statements create more open questions than help with precise answers: Who is Brahma, what is Brahma loka, what is 'X', what says the exact textual reference?

Comment: @jowehler that number 1/1,000,000 is a precise numerical prediction, only so far as experimental observations conform to it. The recent findings however denote that not all observations seem to suggest the exact time dilation. For example it has recently been (atleast according to articles that I read) that quasars do not seem to show exact time dilation as we know the process. So my take is that numerical values can never be used to verify scriptural statements, since numerical values will be tweaked as new findings are observed. So how can one be used to verify the other.

Comment: The very finding that 'time is different in different planes' as said by Brahma denotes that this phenomenon has been used in Hindu scripture and I'm sure other scriptures as you mentioned. However this is not like 'Gods have different time scale than humans' as you mentioned. It is specifically, different 'lokas' or 'worlds' or 'planes' have different time scales. Refer to the story of kakudmi [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakudmi] for one such text "time runs differently on different planes of existence" Sir you can also refer the below answer for more such overlaps between the findings Sir

Comment: @Sai In my opinion, the current questions concerning time dilation and quasars illustrate that we have many open questions about quasars and the early and distant universe. But in my opinion the recent observations do not take into doubt the general theory of relativity. Nevertheless, I agree with you that science moves on by the principle of conjecture and refutation. And in the domain of quantum gravitation at least, we need to extend Einstein's theory. Let me repeat: Who is Brahma, where is Brahmas loka, what is the numerical value of 'X'? Why can we trust in the story of Kakudmi?

Comment: @jowehler okay so keeping things simple (as I believe these definitions are pretty over-simplified and you can feel free to start a separate discussion about this) Brahma is a Being who is the Lord of the Brahma Loka, which is a 'world', not necessarily a planet, perhaps a separate universe or even a collection of all known universes (check multiverse theory for more about this). One day of Brahma is generally described as 8.64 billion human years. Brahma is attributed as the creator God. I definitely suggest that we can start a chat about this since it is straying away from the above.

Comment: Sir As for 'Why can we trust in the story of Kakudmi', the same can be asked for the numeric calculations that you mentioned. The presence of a number which in itself is unable to account for all observable phenomenon (like the quasars) is as vague to me as these stories seem to you. I think you seem to believe that the presence of an exact number would be able to verify the statements in Hindu scriptures whereas I am of the point that the concepts elucidated by Hinduism are only now being uncovered by science and that only is proof enough that hinduism is not a contradiction of science Sir.

Comment: @Sai In my opinion, old texts from Hindu and other cultures contain many assertions, some are right, some are wrong and some are open to interpretation. On the other hand, findings from science are not only claims, but they derive from a theory behind. And the theory explains much more phenomena, not only the one assertion in question. A scientific theory is more general than the specific case. The theory does not only state "that", it also answers "why?". I miss any theory behind most assertions from Vedas or Upanishads - not to mention the tales from Puranas.

Comment: @jowehler I understand what you are saying Sir. I respect your opinion. But from what I understood, science usually deals with this: "we observe X, we observe Y, we observe Z, X causes Y, Y causes Z", for example we can say atoms possess magnetism, magnetism causes attraction/repulsion. So that explains the 'why' of attraction/repulsion, but it does not explain 'why' do atoms possess magnetism in the first place. Later on science says that there certain X, Y sub-atomic particles responsible for magnetism, and these cause magnetism in the atoms. But 'why' do those sub-atomic particles have it?

Comment: @jowehler this is kind of a bottom-up approach. (i.e.) we observe X, what is the reason for X => we observe Y, Y is the reason for X, now what is the reason for Y => we observe Z, Z is the reason for Y. Science deals with taking observable facts and then using them to explain other observable facts. Whereas religion is a top-down approach. For example, religion starts with the unobservable! For example, have you ever watched your thoughts? Have you ever wondered how seemingly co-incidental 'flashes' occur giving you understanding of things? Do you think it is because of 'atoms' moving around!?

Comment: @jowehler Hinduism (atleast Advaita) says that all of observable facts are observable only because of the five senses. That itself puts in doubt their existence/non-existence. Basically that observable is not limited to/explained because of our five senses. Hinduism says that scientific reasoning begins with the Mind. Watch your Mind, watch your thoughts, then one will understand the unobservable, feel the unreasonable! Just as science contains theories, which can be verified by doing experiments, religion also contains theories, but verifying them requires mental experiments! Hence confusion

Comment: The question was "the most prominent example being Christianity and its disagreement with evolution. So how does Hinduism deal with this?" and you haven't covered Evolution at all but go on to quote things like "Hindu are more exact in astronomy and astrology than any other people." Astronomy is a natural science whereas Astrology is a pseudo-science and it's been disproved by Indian scientist **Jayant V. Narlikar**. You can read about his experiment **An Indian Test of Indian Astrology** [here](https://www.csicop.org/si/show/an_indian_test_of_indian_astrology).

Answer (score 3):

There are already answers which tell the answer to your question. I impose a question: why are the contradictions or whatsoever you want to call it arise?

The answer is we humans interpret, compare and discriminate between science and vedas. Science and vedas must not  be compared, they are two completely different things.

Science is modeling of universe with the help of tools like mathematics. It is all about observation and interpretation of nature. There are domains in science which itself are separate but rely on each other in terms of their assumptions. For e.g. chemistry is study of matter without referring to the internal structure of the atom itself. Science is 'study'. I will not answer about evolution as I dont know about it. Take another example: physicst or scientist try with there full force to experiment on astrology.
Take this paper for instance: http://www.thoughtnaction.co.in/an-indian-test-of-indian-astrology/
The paper is written by Jayant Narlikar titled "A statistical test on astrology". But science has no ability to test astrology in first place. Why? If we start studying astrology we come across two bodies called Rahu and Ketu which are not actual planets but intersection of orbits called nodes. At this point itself the 'physical' aspect of astrology is seen. Astrology is asked to provide a mecanism and often scientists make a mistake to take gravity as a mediator of astrology which cannot be true since there is no physical body to produce a gravitational effect at nodes. This is the part of science.

The real problem is also in us, to just show science go hand in hand with vedas etc. We search for similarity and interpret it in our own way. The interpretation as one of the answer does here for Dashavtar and evolution. Why would somebody encode evolution into dashavtar, what about other avatars of vishnu? And why it became clearer when Darwin purposed the theory of evolution, people could not come up with it earlier! Same goes for many things, science discoverd light bulbs, oh see it was written in vedas long ago. These kind of statements are simply for people who are neither into the field of science nor completely devoted to god. The use of these is ok as long as we need to attract morden 'science' children into the domains of spirituality. Ofcorse there are certain many things which go hand in hand with both science and vedas.

The simple conclusion to avoid these things is to fix in mind that we cannot compare, we must not. In the regime of Hinduism itself, the boundaries are not clear. Hinduism gives us the art of living, science also gives it. What you follow is diffrent part. In there purest and deepest parts both the scientist and a devotee do not care about what world says. At last:

> ब्राह्मण्डलक्षणं सर्व देहमध्य व्यवस्थितम्। साकारश्च विनश्यन्ति
> निराकारो न नश्यति॥

The symptoms of universe reside within us. Those with form are bound to be destroyed, while those without form are free from being destroyed.
-Gyaan sankuli tantra translated from verse (29)

(Weather you look outside or inside it does not matter, what matters is getting knowledge and attain a Realization.)

Answer (score 2):

Very good question. I know you reserached some and posted as an answer but I want to add some points anyways:

**(1)Does Hinduism and science contradict each other?** Yes and No. There is a good level of agreement in many areas and we do disagree in several areas as well. For instance Vedic tradition accepts that there is soul in plants and life is a symptom of soul. Science (Jagdish Chandrabose) has proved that life exists in the plant. In the realm of cosmology there is agreement on the existence of different planets as well. However we diagree on the relative positions and some details. You can search on google and check for Richard L. Thompson's Vedic Comsology pdf and video for comparisons and contrasts in this area.

**(2)You asked specifically about evolution theory.** In this area Vedic literature and view is actually in disagreement with Darwin. First of all Darwin's theory is not science. It is his speculation based on limited obseravation and intelligence. Science means you should be able to prove it through experiment. I have never seen in my experience monkeys becoming humans. Srila Prabhuada, one of the prominent Gaudiya Acaryas, suggests that Darwin might have taken some information from padma purana about various species and added his speculations to comeup with the theory. You can find the padma purana verse and translation here http://nitaaiveda.com/All_Scriptures_By_Acharyas/Puranas/THE_FIFTH_VEDA_PURANA/LESSON_FOUR_PART_2.htm Basically there are 8,400,000 species and they are classified into different categories. However the evolution doesn't happen on a bodily level. It is not that monkey body changes to human body. The soul with in the body takes on different bodies. As stated in the Bhagavad Gita 2.22:

> vasamsi jirnani yatha vihaya navani grhnati naro ’parani tatha
>   sarirani vihaya jirnany anyani samyati navani dehi
>
> As a person puts on new garments, giving up old ones, the soul
>   similarly accepts new material bodies, giving up the old and useless
>   ones.

But what kind of body we get in next life is dependent on our activities in this life. Similarly our present position is a reflection of our past activities. All this is determined bu the superior authorities just like a criminal's punishment or a good citizen's reward is judged by the government officials.

> To support the above idea here is a reference from Srimad Bhagavatam
>   3.31.1 by Lord Kapiladeva sri-bhagavan uvaca karmana daiva-netrena  jantur dehopapattaye striyah pravista udaram  pumso retah-kanasrayah
>
> The Personality of Godhead said: Under the supervision of the Supreme
>   Lord and according to the result of his work, the living entity, the
>   soul, is made to enter into the womb of a woman through the particle
>   of male semen to assume a particular type of body.

I understand further we can use another example Lord Krishna gives in the gita 2.13. There He says 'As the embodied soul continuously passes, in this body, from boyhood to youth to old age, the soul similarly passes into another body at death. A sober person is not bewildered by such a change.' So Krishna is saying we can see that the soul is taking on a new body even this life. According to science also the cells in our body are completely replaced after a certain period.

So in regards to this matter what Krishna says in Gita and our information from scriptures like Bhagavatam and Padma purana is more rich and logical than Darvin's speculative theory. In summary, on this matter, I find Vedic information to be more scientific since I can see in my own experience how my body is changing in this life and how I am suffering the results of my good and bad deeds in this life as well. Similarly the pheonmenon continues to next life and it seems logical as well.

**(3) If I am a Hindu, does that mean that I cannot accept what science has researched?** We will accept only to the extent of it's validity. The computer you are working on, the motor cars etc. are all real even though temporary. So there is no blind criticism of science. The brain of a scientist is also a creation of God. Real point it how we use the scientific inventions. As long as they are used for the right purpose we are OK with it. The main thing we need to careful about is that there are so many scientific anamolies. That is science explains something and then realizes it was wrong. For instance the US government, based on science, encouraged a diet heavy in meat. Now they are promoting more greens and grains. In regards to those it is better to take information from Vedic sources. In the matters where science contradicts completely from Vedas it is better to take time tested Vedic information as long as it is not fanatically interpreted.

**(4)Does Hinduism itself make any mention of how to deal with scientific findings that may not line up with the Vedas?** Hinduism puts sastric injunctions as priority.

In Gita 16.23 Lord Krishna says:

> He who discards scriptural injunctions and acts according to his own
>   whims attains neither perfection, nor happiness, nor the supreme
>   destination.

However sastra cannot be properly understood unless we recieve them from practicing authorities. There is a lot of room for misinterpretation. Therefore it is recommended as 'maha jano yena gatah sa pantha', we should walk the path of mahatmans who have preoprely realized the Vedas. See the scientific issue in question in the light of sastra (Scripture), sadhus (saints) and guru (specific saint, the spiritual teacher). Then decide on the level of your faith on what to do :)

Comment: Science also covers theories as long as they are logical and have evidence. Not just things that you see with your eye.

Comment: "First of all, Darwin's theory is not science. It is his speculation based on limited observation and intelligence." - It is a "speculation" only if one doesn't understand how science works. See [Evolution as theory and fact in the literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_as_fact_and_theory#Evolution_as_theory_and_fact_in_the_literature). To quote from Wikipedia: "The basic theory of evolution has been confirmed so completely that most modern biologists consider evolution simply a fact." (Ernst Mayr) "evolution is as much a fact as anything we know in science." (Kenneth R. Miller)

Answer (score 2):

Science itself never and can't contradict with hinduism. Only some partial (adhuri) knowledge scientist try to contradict. When knowledge of one topic is limited to someone (scientist) then they start to believe on behalf of that limited/incomplete knowledge and rejects all other (full) knowledge. Here is how...

The purpose of both science and our scriptures is just to tell truth about world. And truth is only one, it can't be different for differet field (science/hinduism). For example Earth is not alone in space, there are lot more in space is present like graha, nakshatra. Both science and our
scriptures told about them and they both also told their quantity also. And they both are right. Hence both science and scriptures only use to tell truth. And as already said Truth is one, so both of them has to show exact same views on one topic. For exaple they both shows list of planets and both are correct on their info.

**So how there can be any contradict if they both tells the same truth?**

If scientist and scriptures are telling something on one topic then they both must tell the same thing/answer towards that topic. And if they are telling different thing/answer about any topic then analysis of one surely gone wrong.

Means, one of them surely misscalculate that's why they came on different conclusion, If both of their analysis were correct then they must have came up with same conclusion or answer, isn't it?

> So who went wrong in their analysis?

First of all let me clear one point, I said in beginning lines that they both can't and never contradict each other. And later I said, if one of them gone wrong in their calculation/analysis of finding truth about any topic (ex. no. of planets in space) then they seems to contradict with each other.

But that contradiction is only result of miscalculation of one field. That's why contradiction occurs. But that contradiction can't be from science but can be from partial knowledge scientist only. Because some scientists came up with wrong calculation that doesn't mean science gone wrong, but instead some scientists gone wrong.

**Why I am saying that scientists gone wrong, why not our great Sages (who wrote scriptures) gone wrong?**

Because they can't gone wrong but only today's scientists can gone wrong. Come up with wrong analysis has become trend among scientists. Here are one example in which we come to know that scientists came up with wrong calculations and ended up contradict with hinduism..

> Earlier, Scientists used to believe that all planets including son use to move around Earth. But our scriptures (Rig Veda) says, [all planets (Earth also) moves around son](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9102/are-there-any-references-to-gravity-in-hindu-scriptures#answer-9103). Here contradict arrised...
>
> This contradiction only arise because one was wrong in his calculation. To remove contradiction, we just need to remove the wrong calculation and then they both will say the same thing. The wrong calculation was done by scientist earlier.
>
> Scientist used to believe everything moves around Earth **until** great scientist Galileo invented Telescope. When telescope invented by Galileo then all started to analyse space with telescope and they found everything is not moving around Earth but instead Earth itself moves around Son.
>
> So because of Galileo, calculation from science gone right and they both(science and scriptures) came up with same answer.

**But can our scriptures went wrong like scientists went wrong some times?**
No, it's not possible. For example, our four vedas(which contains every possible information) are created by great sages but the information stored in them are provided by Lord himself. And Lord is the creator of world. So our scriptures can't tell wrong info because it was invented by creator of world himself. I mean who can tell better that whether everything
moves around Earth or around Son except creator of Son/Earth? No one...

The thing is scientists are also human, and they also can get wrong easily. And gets wrong mostly. For example: Earlier Scientists used to belive that universe is created cause of Big Bang.
They did present Big Bang theory to tell how universe is created. We all read about Big Bang theory in 10th class/standard. People are reading this since many dacades. But after long time Scientists
came up with new conclusion that rejected their own created theory. Now, even NASA has rejected Big Bang theory which we all used to read or belive since long.

There are lot more examples can be found where scientists gone wrong.

**Note:** Scientists don't only contradict with hinduism but they contradict with each other also coz of their partial/wrong knowledge. For example: some scientist says Donosour ends coz of poisons gass, some says coz of deseas, some says coz of volcano explosion starts their destruction and so on.

Getting wrong is habit of inpatient human of today's time, and scientists are no exception of this. So one should not bother if some scientists contradict with Hinduism because doing contradiction is habit of scientists to prove himself right and other wrong. That's why they do contradict with religions and with other scientists also.

Comment: "Only some partial (adhuri) knowledge scientist try to contradict. When knowledge of one topic is limited to someone (scientist) then they start to believe on behalf of that limited/incomplete knowledge and rejects all other (full) knowledge."No scientists test hypothesis mostly via experiments and if they do not know the answer they will say it. Hinduism however asserts many things and giving zero proof.

Comment: "Now, even NASA has rejected Big Bang theory which we all used to read or belive since long." No NASA hasn't rejected this. Where did you read this?

Comment: @wikash_ Simple google search will tell you that NASA hasn't accepted Big bang theory till now. Few years ago, Nasa did an experiment to test this theory, in which he call all famous  scientist in which Dr. APJ Abdul Kalama was also invited. They all did experiment of making collision of atoms to recreate mini version of big bang but result came out different than they were expecting. Hence bing bang theory failed.

Comment: @wikash_ Every invention like Earth revolve around sun, gravity, 9 planets, stars and so more is already there in our vedas even before existence of science. few centuries ago scientist descover 9 planets but we use to worship nava graha thousands of years before. Hence proved our vedas are for more advanced and superior than science. Whatever descovery science did and will do is already in our vedas. So there is no Q. left of not trusting vedas.

Answer (score 1):

Of course science and Hinduism contradict each other. But science contradicts every religion as far as both strive to explain the phenomena around as. Religion satisfies many other goals. But due to your question I focus my answer on the domain where both overlap.

Science proceeds according to the method of conjecture and refutation. A scientific theory is a coherent set of hypotheses, which are intersubjectively testable. Scientific theories are often refuted by the test. Or the next generation replaces them by more powerful theories. That's not a shame. Rather it is the reason for scientific progress. Science develops theoretical terms and schemes which often go far beyond our every-day concepts. They may even by counter-intuitive.

On the other hand, religions take their explanations from times very far in the past. Religion are always eager to keep the original wording of the text. Changes are often considered a change to the worse. In addition, often religions take their concepts and models from every-day life and extrapolate. Many models are both anthropocentric and anthropomorphic. They are presented as myth. E.g., the beginning of the Brhadaranyaka Upanishad. There are fundamental statements of Hinduism where even the terms are difficult to grasp. "Atman equals brahman" is the source of endless discussion and evokes many subjective interpretations. But what does the equation explain, how to test it?

Summing up: I consider Hinduism a fascinating culture. Full of colour and phantasy, more than any other culture I know. But it is of no use to discuss scientific questions on the base of a religion. Any attempt ends with defending religion by justifications which do not convince me. Some of the above answers provide examples.

Comment: Why don't you read the works of westerner , David Frawley. Might dispel some of your misconceptions about Hinduism and remove Western-culture-tinted glasses when trying to understand it.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to David Frawley, which links me to "Hinduism Today". In my statement above I tried to argue how and why religion and science differ where both overlap. Apparently, you do not agree. So I would enjoy to understand your counter-arguments. I have some background in Hindu studies from an academic point of view. This also includes "Western" authors like Wendy Doniger, John Brockington or Gavin Flood.

Comment: Thank you for being so gracious. I tend to get worked up with incorrect and limiting interpretations which result in distortion of sanatana dharma. Such interpretations are usually influenced by our culture and environment which do impose some limitations on our understanding of other cultures and ideologies. When you have some time, please listen to . While I am in no way learned in Hinduism, we can certainly share views and help each other understand things better.

Comment: You write "please listen to ". Is there a word missing? To whom or to what you recommend to listen?

Comment: Oh yes. I was going to recommend Swami Vivekananda's speech at the Congress of World Religions but am not sure if that is necessary. FWIW, no harm in listening.

Comment: Sir, can you tell me how many digits are there between 0 and 1?

Answer (score -2):

It depends on what you mean by Science, and what you mean by Hinduism.

We can all accept that Truth cannot contradict Truth.

Science is in the business of pursuit of Truth - because they believe the highest Truth is yet to be discovered. So they are bound to take baby steps and make mistakes along the way.

Hinduism is in the business of revealing Truth - because they believe the highest Truth has long ago been discovered. So they are bound to order through Shastras and never ever be proven wrong.

When it comes to falsifiability (ability to prove a statement False by evidence against an assertion), there is no difference between the two, as explained in this [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34352/is-religion-different-from-science-especially-when-it-comes-to-falsifiability)

When it comes to No True Scotsman fallacy (no matter how many 'wrongs' Hinduism has, Hindus will never accept those wrongs as part of Hindu scriptures) - people need to realize that each of the 4 Yugas has its own set of rules - If you apply Treta Yuga Smritis to Kali Yuga, that is a fault of the person who read the user manual for a different version, not a fault of those who wrote the manuals.

Btw, the theory of atheism (materialism or lokayata) propounded by Brihaspati, the theory of atoms (nyaya) propounded by Kanada - what is generally accepted as modern science - were all debated, partially accepted, and eventually defeated in [Brahma Sutras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma_Sutras) of Veda Vyasa 5000 years ago.