# Are there any references to Gravity in Hindu Scriptures?

Tags: vedas, scripture, puranas

Are there any references to Gravity or any fundamental forces in Hindu Scriptures viz. Vedas, Upanishands and Puranas or any Scientific Vedic Scriptures?

Comment: You may find this interesting. It is not about gravity but time. I is from *Bhagabatam* cant remember the exact number. God has created the universe (the material universe) but none of its matters was reacting to each other. Then god enter himself as time (kaal).

Comment: @Sisir Thanks for comment. Now i know some info about "time in Hindu scriptures". I want references about Gravity and other fundamental forces.

Comment: Anil- an interesting reading for you http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/bhagvatpurana24.html . Lord Narayana used his ojas shakti to place the heavenly bodies in their orbits. He uses his sahas shakti to keep them in place across time. So Narayana's sahas may probably be likened to gravity.

Comment: Its sankarsha sakthi which holds the planet together its mentioned in vedas and puranas. Sankarsha otherwise mordern sceintific term is Gravity, one which pull down...The lord is Anantha serpent which always moves through the surface. So Sankashna is also called sesha or when every thing is destroyed in the universe in pralaya but the gravity is still remaining tha is why Adi Seshsa. Sesha is leftover remains

Comment: Universe sit on top of sesha

Comment: Sesha is said to hold the universe in hinduism

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Due to the *dominance* of Vedanta school in present time, Sanatana Dharma **(Hinduism)** is often seen only in the light of Vedanta. If we go with respect to doctrines, Vedanta is only a small part of philosophies of Sanatana Dharma.

**Sanatana Dharma** is mainly represented by six philosophies like Vedanta, Mimamsa, Nyaya etc.. Among the six school of philosophy, [**Vaishesika**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaisheshika) is one of them. Vaisheshika philosophy was founded by Maharsi Kanada.

Just as Vedanta is represented by Brahma Sutra in a concise manner, Vaishesika philosophy is concised by Vaishesika Sutra. [**Vaishesika Sutra**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vai%C5%9Be%E1%B9%A3ika_S%C5%ABtra) are very old texts. Even the western indologists date it to **older than 500 BCE.** And Vaisheshika Sutra clearly discuss about Gravity in the Sutras themselves.

Vaishesika Sutra discuss about role of Gravity in mainly **three events:**

### 1) Why does an object held fall when you let go?

To describe this first of all Sutra [5.1.6](https://archive.org/stream/thevaiasesikasut00kanauoft#page/152/mode/2up) states:

> आत्मकर्म हस्तसंयोगाश्च । 
> Action of body and it's members is also from conjunction with the hand.

As the above Sutra describes that it is due to conjunction with hand object remains. Then the next Sutra describes that in the absence of conjuction falling results due to Gravity.

> संयोगभावे गुरुत्वात्पतनम ([V.S. 5.1.7](https://archive.org/stream/thevaiasesikasut00kanauoft#page/154/mode/2up)) 
> **In the absence of conjunction falling results from Gravity.**

Thus it clearly recognizes objects fall downward due to Gravity.

### 2) Why does an object thrown in air fall after sometime?

Then Vaishesika Sutra discuss role of Gravity in falling of moving objects. It gives through the analogy of arrow.
First it gives mechanism of arrow projection in Sutra [5.1.17](https://archive.org/stream/thevaiasesikasut00kanauoft#page/158/mode/2up)

> नोदनाद्यभिषोः कर्म तत्कर्मकारिताच्च संस्कारादुत्तरं तथोत्तरमुत्तरं च ।। 
> The first action of arrow is from impulse; the next is resultant energy produced by the first action, and similarly the next next.

Then it explains why it falls in next Sutra.

> संस्काराभावे गुरुत्वात्पतनम ([V.S. 5.1.18](https://archive.org/stream/thevaiasesikasut00kanauoft#page/160/mode/2up)) 
> **In the absence of resultant/propulsive energy generated by action, falling results from Gravity.**

### 3) Why does water fall (and rise) ?

Then the Sutras discuss cause of falling of water from sky.

> अपां संयोगाभावे गुरुत्वात्पतनम ([V.S. 5.2.3](https://archive.org/stream/thevaiasesikasut00kanauoft#page/162/mode/2up)) 
> **The falling of water in absence of conjunction is due to Gravity.**

Then it discusses flow of water.

> द्रवथ्वास्यन्दनम् ([V.S. 5.2.4](https://archive.org/stream/thevaiasesikasut00kanauoft#page/162/mode/2up)) 
> Flowing results from fludity.

Then it discusses why water rises.

> नाड्यो वायुसंयोगादारोहणम् ।([V.S. 5.2.5](https://archive.org/stream/thevaiasesikasut00kanauoft#page/162/mode/2up)) 
> The Suns rays (cause) the ascent of water through conjunction with air.

Thus from above Sutras, we can acknowledge that Vaisheshika Sutra clearly discuss Gravity. It uses the word "Gurutwa" which is also used in present time to represent Gravity. Gurutwa means force which arises due to mass.

*However Vedanta School in Vedanta Sutra/ Brahma Sutra doesn't discuss about Gravity. In my view it is because it doesn't think Gravity is a worthy thing to be discussed as Vedanta Sutra are related to realization of Brahman and topics like Gravity aren't worthy to be discussed in Brahma Sutras.*

One can read Vaisheshika Sutras with translation [here.](https://archive.org/stream/thevaiasesikasut00kanauoft/thevaiasesikasut00kanauoft_djvu.txt)

Comment: With all due respect sir, these are hardly insightful. Even without knowledge of gravity, everyone knows that things fall downwards on the earth. We can give all these phenomena whatever fancy names we want, but that does not mean we discovered the concept of gravity. Nor, is saying that gravity is a energy or force, makes us any wiser until we know what force is. Did the vaiseshikas mention that whatever thing pulls an object towards earth, that same thing also keeps moon and earth in orbits? If not, please allow me to say that the above sutras are not related to the concept of gravity.

Comment: @zero 1) question asks about references to gravity which is answered. Also sutras by nature are like seeds can be pretty insightful to someone while someone might not understand at all. 2)Even without knowledge of fire everyone knows it burns but still our Vedas describe Agni 3) It is not a fancy name it is properly defined as 'Gurutva'. See etymology. It means which comes from mass. It's not called something like Indratva(electric) 4)It might make one wiser also. Kanada is wise Rishi. 5)By anumana on above sutras it's the same thing 6)yes these above concepts describe how water boils, agreed!

Comment: Sir, again, not to stretch the argument but 3) I checked etymology and heaviness or weight is one of the meanings mentioned (I do not know if ancient vaiseshikas has a concept of mass), the key to the concept of gravity is the understanding that it acts between any two masses, while I only see objects falling on to earth being mentioned above.

Comment: The Sanskrit dictionaries I checked give "weight" or "heaviness" as some possible meanings of gurutva. To me, it appears that, **गुरुत्वात्पतनम** in the sutras means **falling due to weight** or **falling due to heaviness**. Of course, if any pre-Newtonian commentator interpreted it in terms of "gravity", I will stand corrected.

Comment: Its comical to see someone hardly aware about gravity themselves arguing about others knowing gravity. Brother, for starters, gravity is not a force, it is mentioned like a force for the sake of newbies trying to understand universe. Gravity is an effect because of warped continuum of space time that is warped in the first place because of weight of an object. Read relativity in detail instead of reading school books on gravity. Kanada is way wiser and you would need Phd to even begin to understand his notes. Newton himself wasn't able to explain why gravity is. It was Einstein who explained.

Answer (score 39):

**MOTION OF EARTH**

**Rig Veda 10.22.14**

> “This earth is devoid of hands and legs, yet it moves ahead. All the
>   objects over the earth also move with it. It moves around the sun.

In this mantra,

> **Kshaa** = Earth (refer Nigantu 1.1)
>   **Ahastaa** = without hands
>   **Apadee** = without legs
>   **Vardhat** = moves ahead
>   **Shushnam Pari** = Around the sun
>   **Pradakshinit** = revolves

**Rig Veda 10.149.1**

> “The sun has tied Earth and other planets through attraction and moves
>   them around itself as if a trainer moves newly trained horses around
>   itself holding their reins.”

In this mantra,

> **Savita** = Sun **Yantraih** = through reins **Prithiveem** = Earth **Aramnaat** =
>   Ties **Dyaam Andahat** = Other planets in sky as well **Atoorte** =
>   Unbreakable **Baddham** = Holds **Ashwam Iv Adhukshat** = Like horses

GRAVITATIONAL FORCE

**Rig Veda 8.12.28**

> “All planets remain stable because as they come closer to sun due to
>   attraction, their speed of coming closer increases proportionately.”

In this Mantra,

> **Yada Te** = When they **Haryataa** = Come closer through attraction **Hari** =
>   Closeness **Vaavridhate** = Increases proportionately **Divedive** =
>   continuously **Vishwa Bhuvani** = planets of the world **Aditte** = eventually
>   **Yemire** = remain stable

**Rig Veda 1.6.5, Rig Veda 8.12.30**

> “O God, You have created this Sun. You possess infinite power. You are
>   upholding the sun and other spheres and render them steadfast by your
>   power of attraction.

**Yajur Veda 33.43**

> “The sun moves in its own orbit in space taking along with itself the
>   mortal bodies like earth through force of attraction.”

**Rig Veda 1.35.9**

> “The sun moves in its own orbit but holding earth and other heavenly
>   bodies in a manner that they do not collide with each other through
>   force of attraction.

**Rig Veda 1.164.13**

> “Sun moves in its orbit which itself is moving. Earth and other bodies
>   move around sun due to force of attraction, because sun is heavier
>   than them.

**Atharva Veda 4.11.1**

> “The sun has held the earth and other planets”

**LIGHT OF MOON**

**Rig Veda 1.84.15**

> “The moving Moon always receives a ray of light from sun”

**Rig Veda 10.85.9**

> “Moon decided to marry. Day and Night attended its wedding. And sun
>   gifted his daughter “Sun ray” to Moon.”

**ECLIPSE**

**Rig Veda 5.40.5**

> “O Sun! When you are blocked by the one whom you gifted your own light
>   (moon), then earth gets scared by sudden darkness.”

Comment: Is there any particular Sanskrit word for "Gravity" other that those words which have meaning "attraction".

Comment: @AnilKumar I edited mntra for Rig Veda 8.12.28 in this mantra the word  Haryataa = Come closer through attraction this means IN one word called Gravity other then this ,I will find and will be edit

Comment: @AnilKumar    गुरुत्व means Gravity in Sanskrit find here http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=naravat&script=&direction=SE&link=yes but this is not mention above mantra

Comment: In Telugu Gravity is called as "Gurutvakarshana Shakti". It's clear that root for this is "Gurutva" which is Sanskrit word for Gravity. Previously i thought it had connection with "Guru"( jupiter) Planet which is most massive among all planets.

Comment: Nice findings, but I feel you require to edit the answer by removing the word for word meaning or arranging them properly so that it doesn't look so big and clumsy. @AnilKumar, BTW according to Einstein's theory of relativity, the gravity(as described by Newton) was no more an exclusive component. In other words "gravity" is more like an effect of space-time curvature. In one of the books I read that, certain rules of gravity observable in earth are too localized and they don't apply in space-time. I might be missing the context here, but my point is that "gravity" as such is not as important.

Comment: @iammilind  Edited  and Anil Kumar  yes we also says "Gurutvakarshana Bal" in Gujrati Bal Means Shakti

Comment: @iammilind i have basic idea of General Theory of relativity. IMO, "Gravity"( Some word in Sanskrit which has meaning equal to gravity) was mistaken or wrongly interpreted as some other word. Gravity seems to be important force in observable material Universe when considered in large scale. As five elements of nature Air,Water,fire,Earth(land),Aakash( ether) were mentioned in Scriptures, i feel there are some  explicit references to gravity.

Comment: @iammilind It's true that in general relativity, gravity is just a distortion of the spacetime metric rather than a force.  But general relativity is incompatible with quantum mechanics, and it's generally agreed that the resolution to that incompatibility is that gravity really is a force, and that the fact that it seems like a distortion in spacetime is just an artifact of certain symmetries of the gravitational field.  (I'm keeping the math at a minimum in this comment since I don't know your background.)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, Yes I have indeed lost much of the science & math background after being in software. Nevertheless, my whole point to Anil was that, Gravity as such may not have been given importance in our scripture due to its non-existent nature. Here "non-existent" means, something which is translated from an effect. For example, a collection of lot of flowing water is known as "River". Now many scholars may not give importance to "River" because it just relates to flow of water. When water stills, it becomes "Pond". Similarly "Gravity" is just 1 aspect of space-time. Nothing technical!

Comment: @iammilind What I'm saying is that gravity being an aspect of space time is an outdated view.

Comment: Can you quote the actual mantras or verses in your answer? You put the word by word meaning of some verses without actually quoting the verses. Also, is there any verse which explains what causes gravity vs. the effect of gravity?

Comment: -1: @BhavinChhatrola, from where did you get the translation of the Vedic verses? [Rig-Veda 1.35.9 tr. by Griffith from sacred-texts.com](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01035.htm) has a completely different meaning: _9. The golden-handed Savitar, far-seeing, goes on his way between the earth and heaven,
Drives away sickness, bids the Sun approach us, and spreads the bright sky through the darksome region._

Comment: @sv. when I search for answer then I got above that i answered , you also welcomed to edit answer...,

Comment: @BhavinChhatrola It's ok to source answers from blogs and other places on the Internet but the onus is on you to verify their content before posting here. If I were to edit your answer I will need to delete verses that do not directly address the question but I usually limit my editing to correct grammar, typos etc. and don't mess with the matter itself. If you want to turn this into a community wiki [click here, on how to do it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

Comment: @BhavinChhatrola Could you please tell me where did you get translation for Rig Veda 10.22.14 ? . Here is the one from Griffiths translation says "That Earth, through power of knowing things that may be known, handless and footless yet might thrive,
Thou slewest, turning to the right, gu;na for every living man."

Comment: @BhavinChhatrola So it doesn't say that earth revolves around sun

Answer (score 9):

***RigVeda Hymn 1.35.9***

Shloka:

> हिरण्यपाणिः सविता विचर्षणिर उभे दयावाप्र्थिवी अन्तर ईयते |  अपामीवाम
>   बाधते वेति सूर्यम अभि कर्ष्णेन रजसा दयाम रणोति ||

My translation:

> हिरण्यपाणिः ...the golden-handed; सविता...sun; विचर्षणिर...very active
>   or busy; उभे...fills; ईयते...so large; अन्तर...distance;
>   दयावाप्र्थिवी... heaven and earth सूर्यम...sun; बाधते...drive
>   away; अपामीवाम...disease; वेति...sets in motion; रणोति
>   अभि...penetrates through; कर्ष्णेन रजसा...removes dark; दयाम... via
>   compassion
>
> The golden-handed Sun, the active, fills (with his rays) the large
>   distance between the earth and heaven. He (the sun) drives away
>   sickness, sets things in motion, penetrates through and removes
>   darkness via his compassion.

There is definitely a hint to gravity here.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is mentioned.

## 1)Why tides occurse?

Vishnu puran 2:4:89

> “अन्यूनानतिरीक्ताश्च वर्धन्यापो हसंती च उदयास्तमनेष्विन्दो: पक्षयो: शुक्लकृष्णयो:”
> It holds Moon responsible for water’s ‘up & down (tide)’.

According to modern science, moon attracts water through it's gravity it means Hindus knew about gravity.

## 2)Why objects fall?

Kanad sutra

> संयोगभावे गुरुत्वात्पतनम
> Every objects fall due to gravity in abscense of conjunction.

## 3)Gravity of sun

Brahmanda Purana 1.2.24.69-72a
[image]
Rigveda 1:35:6
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Praśnopaniṣad 3.8](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/prashna-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145314.html) and Śaṅkarācārya's commentary make a reference to gravity.

> Verse 3.8
>
> आदित्यो ह वै बाह्यः प्राण उदयत्येष ह्येनं चाक्शुषं प्राणमनुगृह्णानः । 
>   पृथिव्यां या देवता सैषा पुरुषस्यअपानमवष्टभ्यान्तरा यदाकाशः स समानो वायुर्व्यानः ॥ ८ ॥
>
> ādityo ha vai bāhyaḥ prāṇa udayatyeṣa hyenaṃ cākśuṣaṃ prāṇamanugṛhṇānaḥ | 
>   pṛthivyāṃ yā devatā saiṣā puruṣasyaapānamavaṣṭabhyāntarā yadākāśaḥ sa samāno vāyurvyānaḥ || 8 ||
>
> 8.
>   The sun, indeed, is the external prâna. He rises favouring the prâna in the eye. **So the goddess of the earth attracts the apâna downwards.** The âkâsa between is samâna. The wind is vyâna.
>   
>   Shankara’s Commentary:
>
> Com. — The sun is the well-known outward Prâna among the Dêvâs. He rises and by his light favours this prâna, lodged in the eye of the body, i.e., helps it with luminosity in the perception of forms. **Similarly the well-known goddess presiding over earth, attracts or controls the activity of the apâna in the purusha and favours its action by pulling downwards; for, otherwise, this body, owing to its weight, may fall down, or being unimpeded, may fly up.** The air in the âkâsa, in the middle, i.e., between the earth and heaven (by the word âkâsa, the wind in it is denoted, as those in a cot are denoted by the word cot) is samâna, i.e., favours samâna, samâna resembling it, in the fact of being enclosed within the âkâsa in the middle. The external wind, vâyu, generally because it resembles vyâna in pervading, favours vyâna. This is the drift.

Comment: I think the only reference to gravity is "this body, owing to its weight, may fall down".  The rest of the passage is about how Bhumidevi goddess of the Earth regulates the flow of air, so that the body does not fall dead due to no air flowing and also the body doesn't float due to too much air flow.  It's not saying that Bhumidevi is responsible for gravity.

Comment: OP only wanted to know if there is a reference to gravity. Clearly, there is a reference here no matter how you interpret it. Yes, rest of the commentary is about air, but that is not what I highlighted in the answer. 'being unimpeded, may fly up' - is also a reference to gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity wasn't about the fact that objects fall to the Earth when unsupported. Everyone knew that.

The discovery was important because it was a [*unification*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation#:%7E:text=the%20%22first%20great%20unification%22) of various phenomena observed - The whole point was that the force that leads to an apple
falling to the earth was the same force that kept the moon in its orbit!

Gravity is so much more than just attraction or causation of various phenomena! Newton's law theorizes the proportionality of the force to masses of the objects, that the attractive force follows the inverse square law -  the fact that every massive object attracts every other massive object - the apple is attracting the Earth too!   Einstein in general relativity says so much more than all this!

Based on all the other answers here and a clear understanding of gravity, it is very clear that **NO**, gravity - as the unifying force of the cosmos - isn't referenced in any hindu scriptures.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).