# Is there any mention of law of motions in Hindu scriptures?

Tags: scripture, puranas, science

Are there any references to laws of motion in Hindu Scriptures like Vedas, Upanishands, Puranas or elsewhere?

**Note:** Answer only from Hindu Scriptures or provide views of Hindu Acharyas on this topic. Don't speculate.

Comment: Related: [Are there any references to Gravity in Hindu Scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9102/1049) and [What are some scientific facts described in Hindu scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17442/1049).

Comment: When were newton's laws formulated?18th cen. How old are hindu scriptures?Vedas are ageless, puranas are at least 5k years old. Acaryas (the most famous ones at least) commented on hindu scriptures which do not contain newton's laws (not in their explicit form).  Acaryas would not speculate on some westerner's fresh discovery of the laws of nature. There is enough to learn in hindu scripture and western science had neither sufficient credibility at the time nor did  it  provide enough reason to use as a framework for articulation, for the Acaryas, including the more recent vidyaranya swami etc

Comment: It is very unlikely to be the case. Newton's laws (which are definitive and tautological), when useful, are helpful in very quantitative analyses. Most of the scriptures we have are very qualitative. Also it should be noted that the second law is a definition and not a law, so it helps only in quantifying a property. The first law does not have a valid case in a universe with mass. The third law is so fundamental that it may have been simply assumed. I don't see much value whether it was discussed or not.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62115/discussion-on-question-by-ajay-is-there-any-mention-of-newtons-law-of-motions-i).

Comment: why would you think there would be?

Comment: @Swamivishwananda Just curious to know

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda It's a pity that the earlier this Qn was closed as "off-topic" due to scientific speculations. Though it is NOT. See the related Qn-s. It got reopened and now again closed as "off-topic" for the same reasons.

Comment: People close topics waaaay to quickly and without enough discussion across all of Stack Exchange. Sometimes I feel that people think it is their job to gatekeep rather than to redirect or help reformulate ideas/questions. Indeed, if one person has been brave enough to ask, perhaps another will find the question relevant. That is, if SE is to be a repository of questions and answers, such gatekeeping just presents more work for everyone involved (particularly if the question is asked again).

Comment: @Parikshitha edited ur Qn, pls see if it's okay?

Comment: @RubelliteFae yes you are right. But this site is "**Hinduism Stack Exchange**" and not "**Science Stack Exchange**". We answer questions about Hinduism , for science answer Physics, Chemistry , Biology , Mathematics et cetera SE are there. And for logic or explanation, these kind of questions can ve asked on Skeptics Stack Exchange or something else. We are a Hinduism forum, not a science explanation forum.

Comment: @YDS The main question is Newton's Laws of Motion. It is not any other Laws of motion. If you want to change the question, you should first know the intent of the author first and then make changes to the question and show where you got the intent. You should edit like you have proposed edit. Your edit is against the intent of OP. Even your edit doesn't make this question on-topic. We don't discuss laws of motion, laws of electricity etc.,

Comment: @Sarvabhouma this Qn is on topic now..else how come Qn like https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26181/12304 can be considered on topic here??? And we r not discussing science theories as it is but their version in scriptures if any...and this is identification request, i don't see any reason to close it as off topic... Scriptures are wide.. there may be references for laws of motion too as mention in the linked Qns...

Comment: @YDS It is off-topic. 1) Don't use broken window logic. Other question is not asking whether the claim is true based on an article. 2) This question is still off-topic because asking about scientific law is present is same as discussing science. This question is based on speculation. This is not identification request. Users should know what is scientific speculation. This question is closed twice. 3) Don't change the questions without knowing what exactly OP wants to know. Comment and asking whether it's ok is not the right way of salvaging the post.