# Were theses verses mentioned in Vaisheshika Darshan?

Tags: identification-request, vaisheshika-sutra

Rumours are that the 3 laws of motion which are discovered by Newton in 19th century were mentioned in [Vaisheshika Darshan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaisheshika).

See http://the-hidden-sector.blogspot.com/2011/10/india-discovered-laws-of-motion-before.html

The 3 verses which claim to be equivalent to 3 laws of motion are:

> 1)  वेगः निमित्तविशेषात कर्मणो जायते |
>
> Meaning : Change of motion is due to impressed force.
>
> 2) वेगः निमित्तापेक्षात कर्मणो जायते नियतदिक क्रियाप्रबन्धहेतु  |
>
> Meaning : Change of motion is proportional to the impressed force and
>   is in the direction of the force.
>
> 3) वेगः संयोगविशेषविरोधी   |
>
> Meaning : Action and reaction are equal and opposite.

Are these verses from Vasisheshika Darshan and authentic?

EDIT: The purpose of this question is not to do scientific speculation like whether these verses are same as 3 laws of motion or not. So, please don't close this question like you did with [this one](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19534/is-there-any-mention-of-law-of-motions-in-hindu-scriptures?noredirect=1&lq=1). I just want to know whether the verses I mentioned really belong there or not.

Comment: If someone could mention the sutra number, I would consider that as a proof.

Comment: I have checked Vaisheshika Sutras. These verses are not present in Vaisheshika Sutras. https://archive.org/details/thevaiasesikasut00kanauoft . Could be present in other literature.

Comment: Check this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9102/are-there-any-references-to-gravity-in-hindu-scriptures

Comment: I am surprised to see that [Hindi Wikipedia](https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A6) also write these verses which are not present in Vaisheshika Sutras.