# The way we are praying God is it correct?

Tags: gods, practice, prayer

I am not an Atheist. After reading Bhavath Geetha, I thought of spreading these wonderful things to my friends. But the problem with our generation is they seek scientific reasoning. So I researched some sites and books. After reading those I had some doubts. So I am going to list out those doubts.

I understood some ideas about big bang theory. So who are all saying this universe is not created by God. This Universe created because of the big bang. Everyone accepted that because of the collision only our universe was created. (But I don't accept because how scientists concluded it when no one was there? So that is also assumption only.) If we assume because of collision only for initiating that collision also we need external force right? I am believing that force is the god. We can't say everything is happening because of science or some force. How come earth was created like that other when other planets were also created? But why earth only is suitable for living? We have oxygen, some other gases, water, Sun, and Moon are you thinking that everything happened co-incidentally? No. Everything is created by one creator and that creator we are calling "God".

We can't call him as God also. Because that word also found by us. Before finding the word "God", God exists. So We don't know how to call him. I am thinking that God is not in human form. Maybe he will be in the form of sun or light. So how to pray god without thinking like he is in human form?

Comment: In Bhagavath Geetha Mentioned that Lord Krishna (Vishnu Avatar) is the supreme soul. He created Brahma, Shiva, and Other gods. So Geetha is saying that praying Lord Krishna is enough to pray the all other gods.

Comment: I didn't understand your question clearly. Title and body are unrelated. Why is the second paragraph in the body and few lines in the first paragrah relevant to the question? Please be specific with the question. Please use @username to reply to comment.

Comment: And asking for Scientific reasons is off-topic for our site. If you are looking for them. We are not the right ones to ask.

Comment: As per my understanding, you are confused about Sceince and Hinduism cntradiction. Many thinks that sceintist are always rights on their words but this is not true. They also went terribly wrong many times. See [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2816/does-science-contradict-hinduism/21919#21919) to know about your doubt. This might help you a little.

Comment: @NogShine Apologize me If My question is not clear. I didn't ask scientific reason for God exists. I mentioned Second paragraph for Reason for god exist to who are all saying creation of universe is because of Science.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Thank you for your reply and waiting for Upanishads

Comment: If you can pray to god in his nirguna rupa, that is well and good. But saying that saguna upasana is wrong, is incorrect.

Comment: Learn nyaya, mimamsa sastras to refute pseudo-science.

Comment: No. Do not be confused. It is said that God gave us the language. Dakshinamurti is said to come and incarnate as guru to teach some Rishis, those taught further. So if you call God "Ishvar", then no problem. As for physical body. Yes God is said to be Niraakaar, without any shape, and Saakaar, with Shape. For example, Krishna is otherwise shown Blue, with yellow garment, two hands, with peacock feather. But at same time Krishna is often said like "He has no form, he has no shape.. et c." Even with-form Gods like Krishna, Shiva, Ganesha, Durga et cetera are said to be formless

Comment: Scientific theories are just that, they are just theories and not proven things. And that *Big Bang* theory is also just one theory and nothing more than that. Just because there is some indication that this universe expanded as a result of some explosion doesn't mean that God doesn't exist, or that He did not create the universe. You said that you read Bhagavad gita. Did you notice that word "God" is mentioned there? See eg verses 11.25 deva-īśa "Lord of lords" and 10.15 deva-deva "God of gods". https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/10/15 So, Lord Krishna is not just some god but He is *deva* ...

Comment: ... namely God or Lord (master or ruler) even of other gods. You also said "I am thinking that God is not in human form." If you read Gita then you should know that it is a conversation of Lord Krishna who is the Supreme Lord or God in human form and his bhakta (devotee) Arjuna. So definitely God is in human form. "how to pray god" Just read the Gita and there you'll learn how to do it, see eg 11.14 https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/11/14 "Arjuna bowed his head to offer obeisances and with folded hands began to pray", and 9.14 and 9.22, also 9.34 https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/9/34