# Do Vedāntācāryas really believe that scripture must be rejected if the controdict logic, including vedas?

Tags: vedas, vedanta

> If the “Scripture” (Shastra) contradicts empiricism and reason - the Scripture must be rejected - this is the view of the Vedāntācāryas.[(Source)](https://www.quora.com/What-is-our-biggest-evidence-that-our-scriptures-are-from-God-or-revealed-by-God/answer/Rami-Sivan?ch=10&share=d135f5b3&srid=ucZAt6)

Is it really the view of Vedāntācāryas. Do this include the Upanishads and the Vedas.

Or according to them(Vedāntācāryas) vedas must be accepted at all costs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Science contradict Hinduism? How to deal with scientific discoveries that don't line up with Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2816/does-science-contradict-hinduism-how-to-deal-with-scientific-discoveries-that-d).

Comment: (1) According to the Ramanuja school, if two reputable sources appear to contradict then one must try to come up with an interpretation that is acceptable to both views. (2) One must be careful to equate a conceptual model with the absolute truth. A model can be useful but one cannot be certain that it is the truth; only that it has some predictive power. E.g. it is useful to model a circle as a polygon with 360 sides with short edges when drawing on a screen. It is also useful to model it with 3600 sides. The two models are very different but neither is  the truth.