Can Hinduism fit with science?
I have 2 doubts.
Why is there only evidence for humanity dating back ~300,000 years?
Also, if the first man is Manu, why does archaeological evidence show that it began in Africa?

Whether Hindu scriptures agree or disagree with modern science is off-topic at HSE, I think. @vedantkavaipatti

Read this post: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2816/does-science-contradict-hinduism-how-to-deal-with-scientific-discoveries-that-d/2818#2818
